# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - JS and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid with data and a button which allows to view / edit the selected record.

When I click the button I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`
The button opens a popup and loads all the information of the chosen record from the gridview in the popup

This is my code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnView" class="btn btn-warning" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick='popup("<%# Eval("UserID") %>","<%# Eval("roletype") %>", "<%# Eval("Username") %>","<%# Eval("Password") %>","<%# Eval("Email") %>","<%# Eval("UserRoleID") %>","<%# Eval("FirstName") %>","<%# Eval("LastName") %>","<%# Eval("Phone") %>","<%# Eval("Address") %>")' Text="View" />
```

Popup function:

```
function popup(idn, roletype, un, ps, em, urid, firstname, lastname, phone,address) {
    var $dropdown = $("#roletype");
    $("#userid").val(idn);
    $("#UserRoleID").val(urid);
    $dropdown.val(urid);
    $("#usern").val(un);
    $("#pwd").val(ps);
    $("#txtFirstName").val(firstname);
    $("#txtLastname").val(lastname);
    $("#txtPhone").val(phone);
    $("#eml").val(em);
    $("#txtAddress").val(address);
    $("#popupdiv").dialog({
        width: 1080,
        height: 550,
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
        },
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Please assist as I've been struggling for hours. Thank you!

Comment: please give your `popup` function code

Comment: $dropdown.val(urid); looks a bit suspect

Comment: I would suggest adding a 'debugger;' statement to the top of the popup function code and see in browser's console if the code breaks in to debug mode. If it does, you should be able to narrow down the issue to which statement causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
```

You need a double vertical bar there for a logical OR.  Should be this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog || ui).hide();
```

Comment: Check what actually gets rendered on the page.  My only other guess is that something that the page puts in for those arguments is causing invalid javascript to be rendered in the onclick attribute.

Comment: what's really weird and doesn't make sense to me is when i use this: `<img src="images/edit.png"  style="width:20px; height:18px; padding-top:0px" onclick='popup("<%# Eval("UserID") %>","<%# Eval("roletype") %>", "<%# Eval("Username") %>","<%# Eval("Password") %>","<%# Eval("Email") %>","<%# Eval("UserRoleID") %>","<%# Eval("FirstName") %>","<%# Eval("LastName") %>","<%# Eval("Phone") %>","<%# Eval("Address") %>")'></>`

It works perfectly.

I would like to use a button and not an image

Comment: Try adding 'return' to popup function call (ex: onclientclick='return popup(....)';